# What does Spark 'Structured API' mean?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I don't know What Spark '**Structured API**' means.

Why is '**Structured API**' so named(or called)?

I would be grateful if you could tell me more specifically.

I'm sorry I do not have perfect English.(
I got help from translator.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two places in spark where you come across 'Structured' keyword:

1. Spark SQL, Dataframes, Datasets - These are APIs that help to handle structured data (data in tabular fashion identified as rows and columns). Using Spark SQL, you can write SQL to read the data and process it. Using Dataframe/Dataset APIs will help to perform transformations on structured data.
2. Spark Structured Streaming- This is to handle stream of structured data coming in from a streaming app, message queues (such as kafka).

Comment: Because it processes 'Structured Data', so it is called 'Structured API'. 
Isn't there anything special mean about 'structured'?